# C++ Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in blackjack program

Tags: c++

I was programming a blackjack game in C++ and encounter this problem several times, even I have googled and searched on SO, their solutions still don't work for me, so I wondered that where it has gone wrong.

When I compile it in Clion, the error reads:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "Blackjack::stand()", referenced from:
>
> _main in main.cpp.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "blackjack.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Blackjack bj;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
        bj.dealerCards.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        bj.playerCards.push_back(i);
    }

    bj.stand();
    return 0;
}
```

`blackjack.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

class Blackjack {

public:
    vector<int> desk; // public only for test, should be protected or private

public: // public only for test, should be protected
    vector<int> dealerCards;
    vector<int> playerCards;

public:
    int hit() {};
    void stand();
};
```

`blackjack_stand.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

#include "blackjack.h"

void Blackjack::stand() {
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your source code file structure, while `blackjack_stand.h` contains the implementation, it indeed was not compiled at all, since compilers normally don't compile header files directly.

You should rename `blackjack_stand.h` to `blackhack_stand.cpp` and compile that file along with `main.cpp`.

Comment: Why cannot `blackjack_stand` be a header file? It implements a function that is defined in `blackjack.h.`

Comment: I see, so .cpp file's priority is higher than header file? Only when .cpp calls .h then the latter one will be compiled?

Comment: @JingGuo It is not a matter of priority; this is how they are defined. "Header files" are called "header files" because they are supposed to be included in a cpp files which are directly fed into compilers. Traditionally (from C) header files don't contain implementations -- they are supposed to include declarations. But in C++, you may add implementation there in some cases such as template functions and inline functions.

Comment: @xuhdev nothing is "defined" regarding user header files, it is just a usual convention of programmers.  This guy could define his function in a `.h` file, it is just a bad idea because it will confuse anyone else (and probably himself).

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `Blackjack::stand` shouldn't be in an header file. Header files are used for declaration and not for definition (see `inline` exception below).

To understand why, we need to learn two new terms:

- Declaration: Notifying the compiler about new class, variable or function. Should be at an header file in the most cases. For example, `void stand();` in `blackjack.h` is a declaration.
- Definition: The actual implementation of this function \ class function. Should be in a .cpp file in the most cases (see exception below). For example, `void Blackjack::stand() { ... }` is a definition.

When the code is compiling, the compiler will read and compile all the regular functions in a .cpp file only once, but it will read header files in every .cpp file's `#include`. By separating definition and declaration, we can make sure our code exist in our program only once.

Exception - `inline functions`: However, sometimes we have a little function and we don't really care if its implementation will repeat more than once. Therefore, we can use inline before the function definition and put it on the header file, we can also define it as a part of a class:

```
class B
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "This code will be in every place it called" << std::endl; }
};

inline bar() { std::cout << "This function too!" << std::endl;  }
```

### Summary

To make sure it only will be compiled once, we should always define our functions in .cpp files and declare them on the header files.